# use cycle2 carousel content loaded from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, carousel, jquery-cycle2

I'm trying to implement the cycle2 carousel on my site, when I use it on regular loaded elements it works just fine, but when I try to use it on ajax loaded the events wont fire, I had tried to use the init function after the data from the ajax was printed like the following :

```
$(".ajax-loaded-content").cycle();
```

tho this code initialize only the regular cycle and hides all the other elements in the carousel... how can I re bind the carousel events ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521870/load-jquery-cycle2-on-loaded-ajax-content

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409476/using-jquery-cycle-and-ajax-to-dynamically-create-a-slide-show-images-dont-lo

Comment: There's also a [`destroy` or `reinit` command](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/#commands) you can invoke. I don't think we have enough information (read: code) to analyze your problem any better.

Comment: both of the answer are right only for cycle2 which not using the cycle carousel.. the first link answer is the code in my question..
I can put here some relevant code.. but its not really relevant.. the problem quit simple ,the cycle 2 carousel loaded on document ready and my slideshow loaded after the document is on ready state, I want to bind new element from the ajax call to the carousel events but cant find the way to do so in documentation